# YUV Player on Linux for streaming video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, media-player, yuv

Is there any YUV video/frame player for Linux? Source code not required. My code will be generating video frames at some interval, typically 30fps but could vary based on performance and other factors. I want to display the new frame available on screen.

Right now, I dump the output of my code to a binary file and then view it later but I want a real-time YUV viewer that I can hook up to my code and keep refreshing the screen. Any tools or tips?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the details here, but since you're saying you "dump it to a file", you might be able to pipe it to a player that accepts pipe input on stdin. That might be some gstreamer application or vooya, e.g.

```
cat myrawfile.yuv | vooya -w 352 -h 288 --color yuv --packing p420
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned details. This would have worked well but I am working on ARM Cortex A9 running Linux and vooya isn't available for ARM Linux, correct? I want something just as you wrote but for ARM Linux, if possible.

Comment: gstreamer is available for ARM; google can tell you how to play raw video over streamer CLI.

Answer (score 0):

For those that might be interested - my eventual solution was to get source code for "yet-another-yuv player" (Yay) and then modify that to accept a frame from V4L2 and display to screen via SDL1.2. I just had to compile SDL for my platform and then link my modified Yay against libsdl.